# DNS propagation: A record and IP change on domain panel and VPS?

Tags: domain-name-system, ip, vps, dedicated-server, a-record

I'm moving my website from a VPS to a dedicated server. In my Domain administrative panel there is a DNS zone where i've changed the A record from the previous IP address to the dedicated server's one.

My VPS is running WHM panel, and there there is an "Edit DNS zone" with different A records pointing to the old IP address.

My question: shall i even modify the items in the "Edit DNS zone" in WHM panel or is it enough to modify the A record in the Domain administrative panel? Thank you for your kind attention.

Answer (score 1):

That depends where the zone is managed.  would say both panels can handle the zone - the question is which one the registrar points to. If the registrar handles the DNS resolution then.... the settings in WHM are exactly totally useless because those servers (dns servers it manages) are never even asked.

Comment: Thank you TomTom, in that case i'll ask for further informations to the provider.